# How can I create a secure random key for AES?

Tags: cryptography, aes, key-generation

I need to generate a lot of shared keys for an AES method which uses in various condition, my concern is how can I generate unpredictable keys? I've had some research on [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) but I don't know how I should use them?

Answer (score 4):

`/dev/urandom` in unix based systems and `CryptGenRandom` on Windows. Most programming languages should provide APIs to generate random bytes such as [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.urandom) in Python.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. The answer to this will be based on your expertise in the process.

For example, if you are a developer, as Terry said, you can use APIs.

If you are a Linux person, you can use Linux command line tools.

If you are a windows guy, and not too expert on the command line, there are GUI tools like **puttyGen** (which i personally has tried and suggested for windows GUI lovers).